# How can I delete selected faces?

Tags: faces

I am making this house. But you see the highlighted faces in my door?

[image]

I don't know where they came from. I tried to delete them by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and then choosing **faces**  but it doesn't do anything..

Comment: It looks like you've pressed **Extrude Individual** instead of *Extrude Region* button in a *Tool Shelf*. Delete them with **X** untill they disappear.

Comment: @MartianCactus in the future please make the title of the question more specific to what you are asking.

Comment: oh ok! This guy told me that you have to press E to extrude. I did that..where was I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you tried to extrude the doors inwards. This leaves the edges in between the two doors, and there are now duplicate faces there. There also appears to be duplicate faces at the bottom of the doors.

Try going to vertex select mode and use box select (B) in wireframe mode to select all of the verticies in the area. Then you can delete them.

Comment: I don't really get it...what did I do wrong?

Comment: So basically you just have to delete the faces twice because there are two faces in the same spot.

Comment: In addition to the answer from @Brandon 
You can indeed just remove the faces but this will result in a non-manifold mesh where two vertexes are stacked upon each other. to clear this issue you can simply select all vertexes and perform the 'remove doubles' action
shortcut menu: 'W'

Answer (score -3):

Bro its not that hard just remove doubles and delete it using x it will be done